# Recent developments in the proof of Fermat's last theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

I posted on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668949/recent-developments-in-the-proof-of-fermats-last-theorem), but was encouraged to post on MathOverFlow instead.

It has been 20 years since Fermat's last theorem was proved by Andrew Wiles.
Has there been any simplification in proof in the last 20 years?
What I do know is only that different proofs of Faltings's theorem were given by Vojta and Bombieri
and Khare-Wintenberger's proof of Serre's Conjecture gives a different proof of FLT (the latter was told to me in a comment on the Mathematics Stack Exchange).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ken Ribet at the 2020 JMM in Denver, CO, "A 2020 View of Fermat's Last Theorem": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mq9BS6S2E2k

Comment: I watched that video right away. The video of Ribet explaining it was exciting. About 50 minutes into that video, Ribet was talking about Khare-Wintenberger's proof of Serre's Conjecture.

Comment: So maybe based on what you saw in the video, you might like to add an answer to your own question, for the benefit of those who have not watched it?

Comment: The proof via Serre's conjecture allows one to avoid difficult results of Ribet and Langlands-Tunnel but requires other non-trivial input so it is not clear that it is really a simplification. But the proof is indeed conceptually simpler.

Comment: @auspicious99 Most of that video was a summary of Wiles's proof, not a simplification in proof. However, the answer to the question might be two results an alternate proof of faltings's theorem and a Serre Conjecture(If there's nothing else.).

Comment: What I'd like to see is a serious technical discussion about how exactly newer approaches make things simpler. What is no longer needed if Serre's conjecture is used instead? Etc. Ribet's talk was for a general mathematical audience, not for people who want gory details.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Serre's 1987 Duke paper contains a proof that Serre's conjecture implies Fermat's last theorem. So if you accept Serre's conjecture, then you don't need anything beyond Serre's 1987 Duke paper. Of course the proof of Serre's conjecture relies on the original ideas of Taylor and Wiles.

Comment: @GH sure, but what goes into the proof of Serre's conjecture is the point. How simpler is Serre's paper+proof of Serre's conjecture vs Wiles+Taylor–Wiles?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I would also like to see an answer along the lines of what you suggested. Do you think starting a bounty would help? Or essentially copy-pasting the current question into another post in hopes of getting a better response?

Comment: @D.R. I think asking a new, focused question on the form "Is Serre's paper+proof of Serre's conjecture (and all prerequisites) simpler than the proof of FLT via Wiles+Taylor–Wiles (and all prerequisites)?"  is worthwhile. Link back to this question if you do.